# Include non-documents in a document library

Tags: 2013, list, library

Our department works on training. We are trying to put together all of our materials into SharePoint. A document library works well for job-aids, training manuals, links to websites, etc. All things that go into a document library.

But we also have just regular content that isn't tied to any document or link and is more like something that would go into a list. Like a suggestion to have a meeting with your manager and discuss subject "x." We haven't found any way to easily put this into the same library of content.

What we currently do is have a content type called "FakeLink" which is based on the link to document content type, we put in a fake url and then the rest of the information as expected.

Does anybody else have suggests or tricks for putting "list" information into a "library"?

Comment: Put it on a site page (wiki) or a publishing page, and use the link to a document like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Document set could be an option when grouping multiple type of content. Here is an example (training institute). 
http://en.share-gate.com/blog/document-sets-making-your-metadata-shine

Also you can add a content type called 'Link to a Document'.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. We are using document sets to group content. The problem then becomes, how do you put something into a document set that isn't a document or a link to a document. That is the problem: we have things that aren't documents or links.